# Why did we let z = k for this equation & How it has infinite solutions?

Tags: linear-algebra

$A=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}1 & 3 & -2 \\ 0 & -7 & -8 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{array}\right)$

This is the equation which written in its linear equation form becomes

$\begin{cases}X + 3Y -2Z = 0 \\
-7Y + 8Z = 0 \end{cases}$

According to videos on youtube to this question and online , where they write:
Let Z = K i.e always
**Q1: My question is why ? Why not just go with Z ?**

Going on to next step:

$Y = \frac{8K}{7}$

Therefore ,
$X + \frac{8K}{7} -2Z = 0 $

In end we will get $x = -8z $

**Q2: Now , My question is: How is that infinite solutions.**

Comment: "*How is that infinite solutions*" $\;-\;$ Because you get a different solution for each $k$, where $k$ is any arbitrary number you choose.

Comment: For this particular solution we can comprehend what you mean. However, it will benefit you in the long run if you learn to phrase your question systematically and ensure you include all necessary information.

Comment: @dxiv I didnt get what u mean.

Comment: @RezhaAdrianTanuharja K. Could you also tell me what more info should I share. I will surely next time.

Comment: @S.M.T Calculate $x,y,z$ for $k=1$, that's one solution. Calculate $x,y,z$ for $k=2$, that's another solution. Calculate $x,y,z$ for $k=\pi^2 + \frac{1}{e}$, that's yet another solution. Should be pretty obvious that there is infinitely many of them.

Comment: Q1: You can indeed stay with Z. "Y = $\frac{8K}{7}$ 
": no, $y=\color{red}-\frac{8K}7.$ 
"X + $\frac{8K}{7}$ -2Z = 0 In end we will get x = -8z": no. $x+3(-\frac{8K}7)+2z=0$ and we get $x=\frac{24K}7+2z=\frac{38z}7$ (but this does not fundamentally affect your questions) Q2: the solutions are $(x,y,z)=(38z/7,-8z/7,z)$ for *every* possible value of $z$. e.g. $(x,y,z)=(38,-8,7)$ or $(38\pi,-8\pi,7\pi).$

Comment: @dxiv There is no difference in k or z ? So , youre actually saying to calculate x,y for z = 1. I am not able to understand what you meant here sir?

Comment: @dxiv The next thing is that x = -8z. So , it actually means to say is that x is -8 times value of z.

Comment: @dxiv The question is. How can we assume any value for z ? We cant say any value of k or z we can assume is what i think. Could u explain more as to what you meant

Comment: @S.M.T Not sure what you mean. For a simpler example, suppose you had just one equation in two variables $x+y=0$. This has infinitely many solutions of the form $(x,y)=(k,-k)$ where $k$ is any real number, because each such pair satisifies the equation $k+(-k)=0$. Your case is entirely similar, except with two equations in three variables.

Comment: In general, to specify a system of equations in three variables we need more than just a $3\times3$ matrix. This and the errors pointed out in a previous comment suggest that there are vital parts of this problem you have omitted. It might help if you include a link in the question to the place where you found this problem; that is, don't just write "as per videos on youtube to this question and online", give us links so we can look it up.

Answer (score 0):

### (1) Background in social terms , which may aid a little :

Imagine looking some Image having 2 young girls with a woman in the middle.

You ask : "Who is that woman ?" , Answer : "Oh , She is the mother of the 2 young girls !"

You : "Ok , Who is the girl on the right ?" , Answer : "She is the younger sister of the girl on the left !"

You : "hmmm , Who is the girl on the left ?" , Answer : "She is the Daughter of the woman in the middle !"

Did we get some information out of the Questions & Answers ? No , we got answers to unknown items in terms of unknown items.

If at least 1 Question had been answered in terms of known items , we would know everything.
Eg : You ask : "who is that woman ?" , Answer : "oh , she is Michelle Obama !"
We can make out that the girl on the left is Malia , the girl on the right is Sasha.

### (2) Background in algebraic terms :

You ask : "what is x ?" , Answer : "x is twice y".
You ask : "ok , what is y ?" , Answer : "y is thrice z".
You ask : "hmmm , what is z ?" , Answer : "z is z itself".

Did we get some information out of the Questions & Answers ? No , we got answers to unknown items in terms of unknown items.

If at least 1 Question had been answered in terms of known items , we would know everything.
Eg : You ask : "what is z ?" , Answer : "z is 6"
We can make out that y is 18 , x is 36.

In Math/arithmetic/algebra Questions , we may be given (or get though analysis) unknowns in terms of other unknowns. We may be tasked with finding (or want to know) the values of those unknowns.
We should avoid giving Solutions where we list the unknowns in terms of other unknowns in the Answers.
We should try to give the Solution in terms of known values.

### (3) Coming to given Equations :

The matrix $A$ multiplied by a vector of unknowns gives the $0$ vector.
That gives these Equations :
$ X + 3Y  -2Z = 0$
$0X - 7Y + 8Z = 0$
$0X + 0Y + 0Z = 0$

When there are no Solutions , we can simply say that & more on.
When there is one Unique Solution , we can simply list that & more on.

In given Case , we see that there are unlimited Solutions ( you can check [Simultaneous Equations](https://brilliant.org/wiki/system-of-linear-equations/) or [Advanced Matrix theory](https://brilliant.org/wiki/solving-linear-systems-using-matrices/) to know more ) , hence we say that we will introduce a "free" variable $k$ , which is "known" to us , because we can assign to it whatever value we want.

Then we say that the Solution ( for each value of $k$ ) is :
$z=k$
$y=8k/7$
$x=-2k/7$

**All unknowns are in terms of knowns.**
**This answers your Q1.**

When $k=0$ , we have $(x,y,z)=(0,0,0)$.
When $k=70$ , we have $(x,y,z)=(-20,80,70)$.
When $k=-70$ , we have $(x,y,z)=(20,-80,-70)$.

**Every value of $k$ gives a Solution , hence there are infinite number of Solutions here.**
**This answers your Q2.**

When we do not use $k$ , & give Solution in terms of $z$ , then it is weird. We might assign a value to $z$ which is invalid , which is not there in Current Case , but can happen in other Case where $z$ is larger than some number , or other Case where $z$ is not larger than 100 , or other Case where $z$ is Even , Etc.

When we use $k$ , we can assign which-ever value we want , without concerns about invalid values.

### (4) Example where new variable is very much necessary :

When we are given $x^2+y^2-4=0$ , we should avoid giving the Solutions like $(x,y)=(x,\sqrt{4-x^2})$ , where we are giving the unknown in terms of the unknown.
We can not even let $x=10,-10,100,-100$ & try to get $y$ , which will be Complex or Imaginary.

Parametric Solution is better :
$(x,y)=(2\sin{\theta},2\cos{\theta})$ , where we introduce new variable $\theta$ which is in our control.
Every value of $\theta$ gives a Solution.
In this Case , the Solutions will repeat , though there are Cases where Solutions do not repeat.

Comment: The moment you write $z=k$ you confirm that $z$ is just as good a free variable as $k$. How do you know it is OK to write $z=k$ if $k$ could be any value and you are not sure that $z$ can be any value?

Comment: That is a little beyond the Scope of this Question , @DavidK , OP wants to know (Q1) why $k$ was used , when Solution can be in terms of $z$ itself (Q2) Why we say there are infinite number of Solutions. I have covered both Points in Section (3). We can plug-in the Solution to check that it works for all $k$. My Section (4) is beyond that Scope to give Examples where new variable is necessary.

Comment: What I was trying to illustrate in my comment was why your Section 3 fails to answer Q1. You cite disadvantages of using $z$ but each one of them applies equally to $k$. There are some actual advantages to using a new variable, but you didn't mention any of them (and in my opinion, it is "weird" to use $k$ in particular as the new variable).

Comment: Maybe your Comment "There are some actual advantages to using a new variable" should be elaborated & converted into Answer format , @DavidK , which may throw more Insight on this. I used the words "avoid" & "weird" , in a loose way. I may not want somebody to claim to know the Exact value of $\pi$ & then give that Exact value in terms Square of $\sqrt{\pi}$ which is not wrong. Like-wise , I may not want to know $(x,y,z)$ in terms of $z$ , though it is not wrong. Some Authors are ok with $z$ , some Authors avoid that & choose $k$ , I myself am ok with either , provided the usage is Consistent !

Comment: I have not posted an answer because the question itself is improperly asked. I am waiting for OP to provide the missing information so that I will know what the question really is.

Comment: I can see the 2 Doubts/Questions OP gave & I have attempted to Answer/Explain Both , in general terms , @DavidK , When OP gives more Details , we might add some thoughts on the Particular Exact Case , though the generality will still be valid.